# Any way to go to previous error with ipdb/pdb?

Tags: python, pdb, ipdb

All to often, I am trying to debug something, and I forget to type

```
debug
```

and jump right to typing a debug command, e.g.

```
u
```

and then I get

```
NameError: name 'u' is not defined
```

And I can no longer debug the original error, only this NameError.

So I need to run my scipt again to generate the error I actually want to debug.

Is there any way to go back to a previous error?  Maybe some hacky way to save it somewhere?

Comment: Python keeps only one raised exception per thread. Though not sure about this.